# Cannot connect XBOX 360 wireless controller on Ubuntu 16.04 ( xboxdrv cannot found controller )

Tags: 16.04, services, gamepad, xbox-360

Hello everyone I am trying to connect Xbox 360 wireless controller via Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04.

First of all, I made sure that my pad was detected and paired by the system:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpszQ.png)

But these colored bars disappear and appear again I don't know why...
Then I found a tutorial on how to connect controller to Ubuntu:
[Link](https://github.com/gotbletu/shownotes/blob/master/xboxdrv.md)

But I can't start these services at all: 

`sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service
sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service`

When I enter `sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service` 
I got an error:

"Failed to execute operation: File exists"

and "Failed to start xboxdrv.service: Unit xboxdrv.service not found.
" when I enter `sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service`

Running `xboxdrv` of course produces an error:

"-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found
"

I am asking for help, I completely do not understand what the problem is...

Comment: You don't need xboxdrv for the Bluetooth Xbox One (it's not a 360) controller. You may need to use Windows 10 to update the firmware on the controller before it will be usable over Bluetooth in Linux, though. Otherwise you need to use the dongle and the controller in Xbox Wireless mode, or connected via USB as a wired controller.

Comment: OK nice to know that it is Xbox One controller. Could you tell me how connect this controller via USB cable?

Comment: Just plug in a micro-USB cable to the port on the front of the controller.

Answer (score -2):

**First** off, there are no Bluetooth Xbox 360 gamepads. Probably you have an "Xbox Wireless Controller", also known as an "Xbox One S controller".

**Second**, you don't need an XInput driver (like xboxdrv or xpad) to use Xbox One controllers over Bluetooth. When connected over Bluetooth, they are treated as Bluetooth HID devices and do not require a driver. So the "No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found" error is probably correct and not an issue for getting this device to work over Bluetooth.

**Third**, there's an issue with the BlueZ Bluetooth stack (which is used by many Linux distros, including Ubuntu) that causes Xbox One controllers to not stay connected. The device will pair successfully and seem to connect, but immediately disconnects. As a workaround, you can set the `disable_ertm` option to 1 which will allow the device to stay connected.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226610

This causes issues that exactly match what you describe with the disappearing signal strength bars so it's likely that this fix will work for you. (Note: you'll need to do this after each reboot, so put it in a startup script if it works.)

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
```

**Fourth**, as mentioned in a comment above there is a firmware versioning issue. This was more of a problem a few years ago but may still bite you on 16.04. Basically, Microsoft decided to update the controller's firmware and changed the Bluetooth HID mode to make it more compatible with Android devices while leaving the USB mode unchanged. When they did that, they essentially made it so the controller, when connected over Bluetooth, looked like a "new" device that wasn't recognized by any drivers or games. It didn't start working again until developers updated their apps with the info for the "new" device. Getting new devices to be supported properly is always a challenge, but in this case it was particularly bad because so many people already had the device and it was broken intentionally. At this point it's less of an issue because most apps support both firmware revisions.

Comment: The `disable_ertm` trick does not always work. The firmware update issue is not limited to 16.04. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu. There were issues in the controller that are fixed in the update. The device ID may have changed, and require a re-pairing, but your description here is inaccurate.

Comment: The BlueZ bug causes issues exactly like the ones described in his question. "But these colored bars disappear and appear again I don't know why..." Yes, the FW update changed the device IDs, but it also changed the HID codes sent for various buttons. HID gamepad drivers rely on these codes to interpret gamepad buttons, so even if a driver recognized the new device ID it would also need to understand the new mapping.